# Export to Excel with PHP fetches all the HTML elements

Tags: php, excel

I have a MySQL table which I want to extract in Excel format, with core PHP. It extracts, but it fetches all the HTML elements of the page and doesn't show the results in cells but in one line. The function for doing the export is:

```
function export()
{
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gdtest");
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');
    if ($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $DB_TBLName = " tblsurveys";
    $filename = "surveys";  //your_file_name
    $file_ending = "xls";   //file_extention

    header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.'.'.$file_ending");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $sep = "\t";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName");
    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) { //fetch table field name
        echo $property->name . $sep;
    }
    print "\n";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {  //fetch_table_data
        $schema_insert = "";
        for ($j = 0; $j < mysqli_num_fields($result); $j++) {
            if (!isset($row[$j])) {
                $schema_insert .= "NULL" . $sep;
            } elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]" . $sep;
            } else {
                $schema_insert .= "" . $sep;
            }
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep . "$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print trim($schema_insert);
        print "\n";
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

I added die(); before the second while's ending, but with no luck. Does anyone more experienced than me can see what is the problem? Something is missing but I can't figure it out.

The picture is what is actually created. The output:
[image: The output]
I hide some personal info
The expected result would be an Excel file with headers and data from the db table.

Comment: can you show us current output vs expected?

Comment: Erik updated my post with an output image